# Is that possible to get an instance of event handler in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

Is it possible to get an instance of eventhandler in C#?
Just like get function pointer in C++

What I want is to get the event handler of a textbox, which might be set differently in different part and different time.

Example:
For a TextBox, we have code like below:

```
TextBox tbUserName;
tbUserName.Click += new EventHandler( (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("bla") } );
```

I want another function be able to get the handler like this:

```
EventHandler h = tbUserName.Click;
```

But it doesn't work. What compiler said, Click only support += -= but not able to be on the right hand side.

Comment: What does different part and different time mean? Can you provide a concrete example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the invocationlist of an event, and from each invocation you can retrieve the Target (can be null for static eventhandler method), and the MethodInfo.

Something like this:

```
public class TestEventInvocationList {
    public static void ShowEventInvocationList() {
        var testEventInvocationList = new TestEventInvocationList();
        testEventInvocationList.MyEvent += testEventInvocationList.MyInstanceEventHandler;
        testEventInvocationList.MyEvent += MyNamedEventHandler;
        testEventInvocationList.MyEvent += (s, e) => {
            // Lambda expression method
        };

        testEventInvocationList.DisplayEventInvocationList();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void MyNamedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Static eventhandler
    }

    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void DisplayEventInvocationList() {
        if (MyEvent != null) {
            foreach (Delegate d in MyEvent.GetInvocationList()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Object: {0}, Method: {1}", (d.Target ?? "null").ToString(), d.Method);
            }
        }
    }

    public void MyInstanceEventHandler(object sendef, EventArgs e) {
        // Instance event handler
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
Object: ConsoleApplication2.TestEventInvocationList, Method: Void MyInstanceEven
tHandler(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
Object: null, Method: Void MyNamedEventHandler(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
Object: null, Method: Void <MyMain>b__0(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

The event is in effect a multicast delegate, and handlers can be specified with the simple += and -= syntax.

For instance...

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // Do something in here...

}

...
...

myButton.Click += myButton_Click;
```

Answer (score 0):

- In C# ,there is no separate event handler type,but the event
  mechanism is built on top of the Delegate type.
- A delegate/multicastdelegate object is similar to a c++ function pointer,that can store
  one , more method addresses and could be invoked.
- C# provides a syntatic sugar in the form of keyword event,which
  then becomes a Multicast Delegate,once the source code is compiled.
- Events can be subscribed to and unsubscribed from

To Subscribe : `<event> += <method>`
To Unsubscribe : `<event> -= <method>`

Code showing three methods subscribing to the same click event

```
tbUserName.Click += new EventHandler( (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("method 1 called") } );
tbUserName.Click += new EventHandler( (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("method 2 called") } );
tbUserName.Click += new EventHandler( (s, e) => { MessageBox.Show("method 3 called") } );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Codelgnote, what I want is to get the "function pointer" so I use it somewhere else.